# Are there any online resources one can use to access raw clinical trial data without having to contact those involved in the study?

Tags: statistics, clinical-trial

I want to do some statistical analysis and I have a preference for real data so I was wondering if there's somewhere I can get such data for free without a heap of bother in phoning those involved in the studies in question.

Comment: Have you seen this question on stats SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18833/where-to-find-raw-data-about-clinical-trials ?

Comment: More options in a similar question on Open Data SE: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11/de-identified-patient-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See these three sites:

- [ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/)
- [NIDA](https://datashare.nida.nih.gov/)
- [ClinicalStudyDataRequest](https://clinicalstudydatarequest.com/)

For clinical trials conducted by other agencies (in different countries), you may have to contact those authorities.