# Source of journals collecting titles of scientific publications regarding clinical trials with dogs fed medicinal herbs

Tags: pharmacology, medicine, literature, clinical-trial

After some time researching on the web, you can find a lot of websites telling you that some herbs may have or have specific properties(unfortunately most seem to be "advertised" as if they were wonder drugs), but none or few give references to specific titles of papers.

Another alternative is the pub med website but papers don't seem to pop up regardless of any search words.

Where is all that research information posted?

Comment: NCBI tends to be a good one. While this isn't about dogs, they have [the effects of mint on exercise](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23517650). However I did find an article about ginseng and dogs [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17610402), [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12819370), and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/157842). To find the dog article I typed "NCBI ginseng dogs" into Google.

Comment: For a lot of "alternative" medicine there are only claims but not serious scientific studies have ever been conducted. Look at [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed), if you don't find them there, they are most likely not existant.

Comment: Check the databases mentioned in [this post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/24611/3340) with right keywords.

Comment: Thanks to all, don't know if it matters but, I was looking for research on something that is anti-inflammatory such as turmeric.